# Create a keyboard shortcut for a button in a windows app?

Tags: api, keyboard-shortcuts

Create a keyboard shortcut for a button in a windows app?

I have an Autodesk Revit app which i use for CAD.

There is a button in this app that does a "Fit to view" command. You click it and a 3D view centers around an object.

The app does not allow me to bind this "action" to a keyboard shortcut in it's current version.

If you use a Spacepilot 3D mouse this action si available to one of its the buttons.

Is there any way to bind this to a keyboard shortcut using some kind of software?

Revit also allows extensions through it's API so this might be a way also.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a "Zoom to awesome" addin that uses the API to do that but only in plan view not 3d camera perspective views like you can do with the viewcube.

http://www.architecture-tech.com/2012/09/zoom-to-awesome.html